# Is parent component re-rendered when the child component returns with something new?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As long as I know, child component is being re-rendered when the parent component's `state` or `props` change.

But I have no idea with the case of vice-versa.

Here is a code.

**usePromise.js (custom made hooks)**

```
import { useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'RESOLVED':
            return { ...state, resolved: action.diff };
        case 'LOADING':
            return { ...state, loading: action.diff };
        case 'ERROR':
            return { ...state, resolved: action.diff };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default function usePromise(promiseCreator, deps = []) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
        resolved: null,
        loading: false,
        error: null
    });

    const process = async () => {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOADING', diff: true });
        try {
            const result = await promiseCreator();
            dispatch({ type: 'RESOLVED', diff: result });
        } catch (e) {
            dispatch({ type: 'ERROR', diff: e });
        }
        dispatch({ type: 'LOADING', diff: false });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        process();
    }, deps);

    return state;
}
```

**usePromiseSample.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import usePromise from './usePromise';

const wait = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(() => resolve('Hello hooks!'), 3000)
    );
};

const UsePromiseSample = () => {
    const { resolved, loading, error } = usePromise(wait);

    console.log('test')

    if (loading) return <div>loading...</div>;
    if (error) return <div>error happened!</div>;
    if (!resolved) return null;

    return <div>{resolved}</div>;
};

export default UsePromiseSample;
```

As you can see above the code, child(`usePromise.js`) component's state is changing four times.

But it seems that parent(`usePromiseSample.js`) is also being re-rendered four times since test is logged four times.

How can I understand this situation easily?

Comment: `usePromise` is not a child component, but a custom hook. The hook itself it not beeing re-rendered, but the component that uses it will. If you would render `UsePromiseSample` inside another component, you would see that the parent is not re-rendering when the `UsePromiseSample` is.

Comment: I'm not sure if we still can use `parent` / `child` vocabulary with hooks. It's matter of dependencies; `usePromiseSample` depends on `usePromise`, so it will be reloaded if `usePromise` state changes.

Comment: Thanks @Tholle, but isn`t that hook itself not being re-rendered? I am confused becuase if we add console.log() to UsePromise.js, it also logs out it four times.

Comment: @soywod thanks for important correction. so we may use the word parent / child for class component, but not for the functional component right?

Comment: It's not about class or function component, but about hooks. It's a different approach. You can't say that `usePromise` is the child of `usePromiseSample`. But `usePromiseSample` uses (or depends on) `usePromise`.

Comment: @soywod aha your right. child / parent word is used when jsx element is rendered inside the parent component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`usePromise` is not a child component, but a custom hook. The hook itself it not being re-rendered when an action is dispatched inside `usePromise`, but the component that uses it is.

If you render `UsePromiseSample` inside another component, you will see that the parent is not re-rendering when `UsePromiseSample` is.

```js
const { useEffect, useReducer } = React;

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'RESOLVED':
      return { ...state, resolved: action.diff, loading: false };
    case 'ERROR':
      return { ...state, resolved: action.diff, loading: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

function usePromise(promiseCreator, deps = []) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    resolved: null,
    loading: true,
    error: null
  });

  const process = () => {
     promiseCreator()
       .then(result => {
         dispatch({ type: 'RESOLVED', diff: result });
       })
       .catch(e => {
        dispatch({ type: 'ERROR', diff: e });
       });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    process();
  }, deps);

  return state;
}

const wait = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve('Hello hooks!'), 3000)
  );
};

const UsePromiseSample = () => {
  const { resolved, loading, error } = usePromise(wait);

  console.log('UsePromiseSample rendered')

  if (loading) return <div>loading...</div>;
  if (error) return <div>error happened!</div>;
  if (!resolved) return null;

  return <div>{resolved}</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  console.log('App rendered')

  return <UsePromiseSample />
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation with code. But it seems that hook itself is being re-rendered since if I add console.log('something') to the usePromise.js, it logs 'something' with four times. Could you please explain this issue too?

Comment: @jwkoo The hook itself is not re-rendering, but the component that uses it is re-rendered. When the component that uses it is re-rendered, the `usePromise` hook will be invoked and any `console.log` inside of it will be run. I'm not sure in what other way I can explain it.

Comment: It was fool to ask this. you are right. re-render the component which is using custom hook when the moment of dispatching. thank you